# R - find out if a the column containing the max value of a row is tied with another column

Tags: r

I have some data with several columns of integers:

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c(0,2,5,6,9,8,7,4,5,6,3,5,4),
                 v2 = c(6,3,5,4,9,5,7,4,8,5,2,3,6),
                 v3 = c(9,6,3,5,4,2,8,7,4,1,2,5,4),
                 v4 = c(6,3,5,2,1,4,1,2,5,3,2,1,2),
                 v5 = c(6,3,2,5,4,1,2,5,3,2,5,6,5))
```

I'm using which.max to find the column with the max value:

```
df$top <- colnames(df)[apply(df,1,which.max)]
```

returns:

```
   v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 top
1   0  6  9  6  6  v3
2   2  3  6  3  3  v3
3   5  5  3  5  2  v1
4   6  4  5  2  5  v1
5   9  9  4  1  4  v1
6   8  5  2  4  1  v1
7   7  7  8  1  2  v3
8   4  4  7  2  5  v3
9   5  8  4  5  3  v2
10  6  5  1  3  2  v1
11  3  2  2  2  5  v5
12  5  3  5  1  6  v5
13  4  6  4  2  5  v2
```

Since this returns only the column name with the first max value I need to find a way to create another column containing TRUE or FALSE where the max value is tied, something like this :

```
   v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 top tie
1   0  6  9  6  6  v3 FALSE
2   2  3  6  3  3  v3 FALSE
3   5  5  3  5  2  v1 TRUE
4   6  4  5  2  5  v1 FALSE
5   9  9  4  1  4  v1 TRUE
6   8  5  2  4  1  v1 FALSE
7   7  7  8  1  2  v3 FALSE
8   4  4  7  2  5  v3 FALSE
9   5  8  4  5  3  v2 FALSE
10  6  5  1  3  2  v1 FALSE
11  3  2  2  2  5  v5 FALSE
12  5  3  5  1  6  v5 FALSE
13  4  6  4  2  5  v2 FALSE
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option would be to get the `max` and check the count of `max` elements by row

```
df$tie <- apply(df[1:5], 1, function(x) sum(x == max(x)) > 1)
df$tie
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

---

Or using `rowSums`

```
rowSums(df[1:5] == do.call(pmax, df[1:5])) > 1
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

NOTE: Both the methods are generalized and can take care of multiple conditions

Comment: Thanks for this, just what i needed

Answer (score 3):

We could use `max.col` exploiting `ties.method`

```
df$tie <- !max.col(df, ties.method = "first") == max.col(df, ties.method = "last")


df
#   v1 v2 v3 v4 v5   tie
#1   0  6  9  6  6 FALSE
#2   2  3  6  3  3 FALSE
#3   5  5  3  5  2  TRUE
#4   6  4  5  2  5 FALSE
#5   9  9  4  1  4  TRUE
#6   8  5  2  4  1 FALSE
#7   7  7  8  1  2 FALSE
#8   4  4  7  2  5 FALSE
#9   5  8  4  5  3 FALSE
#10  6  5  1  3  2 FALSE
#11  3  2  2  2  5 FALSE
#12  5  3  5  1  6 FALSE
#13  4  6  4  2  5 FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
df['tie']=rowSums(df[1:5]==apply(df,1,max))>1
df
   v1 v2 v3 v4 v5   tie top
1   0  6  9  6  6 FALSE  v3
2   2  3  6  3  3 FALSE  v3
3   5  5  3  5  2  TRUE  v1
4   6  4  5  2  5 FALSE  v1
5   9  9  4  1  4  TRUE  v1
6   8  5  2  4  1 FALSE  v1
7   7  7  8  1  2 FALSE  v3
8   4  4  7  2  5 FALSE  v3
9   5  8  4  5  3 FALSE  v2
10  6  5  1  3  2 FALSE  v1
11  3  2  2  2  5 FALSE  v5
12  5  3  5  1  6 FALSE  v5
13  4  6  4  2  5 FALSE  v2
```